# Function worked, now RangeError

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting a `RangeError: Maximum call stack exceeded` error? I am trying to parse through text to find math and solve it. It was working until I started to implement parenthesis'. I have tried to find the error but I just can't figure it out.

My Code:

```js
var alg = {
        calc: function(eq, solveFor) {
            var out;
            var sideOne = eq.substring(0, eq.indexOf('='))
            var sideTwo = eq.substring(eq.indexOf('=') + 1)
            if (sideOne === solveFor) {
                alg.simplify(sideTwo);
            }
            if (sideTwo === solveFor) {
                alg.simplify(sideOne);
            }
        },
        simplify: function(eq) {
            str = $.trim(eq);
            if (str == undefined) {
                console.error('Error: null string')
            } else {
                var charMatch = /^[\d\*\/\+\-\^\(\) ]+$/
                if (charMatch.exec(str) === null) {
                    console.error('Error: Invalid char/expression')
                } else {
                    alg.parMath('not');
                    alg.expRoot(solve);
                    alg.multDiv(solve);
                    alg.addSubtr(solve);
                }
            }
        },
        fromPar: function(par) {
            alg.parMath(par);
            alg.expRoot(solve);
            alg.multDiv(solve);
            alg.addSubtr(solve);
        },
        parMath: function(source) {
            var reP = /\(([\d\*\/\+\-\^\(\) ]+)\)/
            var exP = reP.exec(str)
            if (source === 'par') {
                str = str.replace(exP[0], solve)
            }
            if (exP !== null) {
                use = 'par'
                solve = exP[1]
            } else {
                use = 'not'
                solve = str;
            }
        },
        expRoot: function() {
            var fracCon = /(\d+)\/(\d+)/
            var reER = /(\d+)(\^)(\d+(\/\d)?)(?!\/)/
            var exER = reER.exec(solve)
            if (exER !== null) {
                var exFC = fracCon.exec(exER[3])
                if (exFC !== null) {
                    var rep = Math.pow(parseFloat(exER[1]),(parseFloat(exFC[1]) / parseFloat(exFC[2])))
                } else {
                    var rep = Math.pow(parseFloat(exER[1]),parseFloat(exER[3]))
                }
                solve = solve.replace(exER[0], rep)
                if (reER.exec(solve) !== null) {
                    alg.expRoot();
                }
            }
        },
        multDiv: function() {
            var reMD = /(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) *([\*|\/]) *(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/
            var exMD = reMD.exec(solve);
            if (exMD !== null) {
                if (exMD[2] === "*") {
                    var rep = parseFloat(exMD[1]) * parseFloat(exMD[3]);
                    var rep = Math.round(rep * 1000000) / 1000000;
                } else {
                    var rep = parseFloat(exMD[1]) / parseFloat(exMD[3]);
                    var rep = Math.round(rep * 1000000) / 1000000;
                }
                if (use !== 'par') {
                    solve = solve.replace(exMD[0], rep);
                }
                if (reMD.exec(solve) !== null) {
                    alg.multDiv();
                }
            }
        },
        addSubtr: function() {
            var reAS = /(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) *([\+|\-]) *(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/
            var exAS = reAS.exec(solve); //Getting RangeError here
            if (exAS !== null) {
                if (exAS[2] === "+") {
                    var rep = parseFloat(exAS[1]) + parseFloat(exAS[3])
                    var rep = Math.round(rep * 1000000) / 1000000
                } else {
                    var rep = parseFloat(exAS[1]) - parseFloat(exAS[3])
                    var rep = Math.round(rep * 1000000) / 1000000
                }
                if (use !== 'par') {
                    str = str.replace(exAS[0], rep)
                }
                if (exAS !== null) {
                    alg.addSubtr(solve);
                } else {
                    if (use == 'not') {
                        out = solve;
                    } else {
                        alg.fromPar('par')
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (use == 'not') {
                    out = solve;
                } else {
                    alg.fromPar('par')
                }
            }
        }
    
    };
    
    console.log(alg.calc('x=(1+1)', "x"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm getting the error at the start of `addSubtr` function (marked by a comment). Can anyone help me find how to fix the error?

Comment: Code doesn't work.

Comment: @vlaz That is the issue, I am getting a RangeError that I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Re-reading my comment, I realise I didn't manage to express what I wanted. I meant that the code doesn't work in a different way than what you described, so I'm not even seeing the range error. It seems like you have invalid syntax.

Comment: @vlaz Is there a way to run jquery in Stackoverflow?

Comment: If you mean in a code snippet - you can add jQuery as an external library - there is a dropdown when you edit the snippet. If you mean just in the browser console, then you should be able to do it.

Comment: @vlaz Thank you, I added Jquery. Now it is returning the RangeError

Comment: OK, this is bizarre then - you have `parseFloat(exER[1]) ** parseFloat(exER[3])` which throws a `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '*'` in Firefox, but it _works_ in Chrome. Instead of multiplying, it raises to the power of the supplied argument `3 ** 2 //-> 9`. It seems like nonstandard behaviour on Chrome's part, since it also errors in Edge and I can't even find references to this for JavaScript (the `**` operator apparently works the same way in Python).

Comment: What is a way to fix it? I am using Chrome so I didn't know it was an issue.

Comment: Well if you indeed want to raise to some power (so, if it's not a typo), you can just call `Math.pow(number, power)`.

Comment: Okay, it was intentional to have the double *. I'll fix that. But, the RangeError issue is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code goes into an infinite loop. Here is the relevant part of the logic

```
addSubtr: function() {
    /* ommitted */
    var exAS = reAS.exec(solve); //Getting RangeError here
    if (exAS !== null) {
        /* ommitted - logic here*/
        if (exAS !== null) {
          alg.addSubtr(solve);
          /* ommitted */
        }
    }
}
```

1. You get the value for `exAS` by parsing `solve` through a regex.
2. If this returns a non-null value you've gotten a match
3. With that hen you go inside the `if` condition and do some logic
4. Still inside there, there is another `if` statement that checks if the regex matched anything. Now, by definition, this would be true - it can be easily seen with a lot of code removed - the same condition is checked for twice. There is nothing that would change the the outcome between the two `if`s.
5. Since the conditional check passes you recursively call the same function again with the same input.

Because the input is the same, the logic will work the same so steps 1-5 are executed again and the function is called again.

This causes infinite recursion. Well, in reality there is a limit and that's the stack size for JavaScript, which is why you are getting the error. It's a bit misleading, since it's the regex that runs over the call stack size, not the recursive call to `addSubtr`, else it would have been a bit more clear what is going on.

For how to fix it - you need to restructure the logic so you don't get into infinite loops. I am not sure exactly what is the best way for your case but I'd suggest working it out yourself - it would be a useful exercise regardless. Here are some pointers

In point `4.` I made, I mentioned that there was an essentially useless check. I assume that it is supposed to be useful. 
 - You may have intended the inner `if` to be outside of the outer one. As it stands now, the two are equivalent so the inner `if` can just be removed.
 - maybe the condition of the inner `if` is incorrect - it could be that you only sometimes want to do the recursive call, not every time.
 - perhaps there was supposed to be something that changes either `exAS` or `solve` or both. Thus either the condition would (potentially) yield a different result the second time it's checked, or the function would produce a different result when called recursively (which would make the recursive call useful) or both.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you have an infinite loop which is here

```
        if (exAS !== null) {
            alg.addSubtr(solve);
        }
```

This is a useless check for two reasons. One because as you notcie exAS is defined in addSubtr. So every time you call this function you are resetting the value.
Your other problems are you are create variables with the same names, and relying off of static variables/ void functions.
If pm me i cant help you workout the correct way to structure this this function and all the other functions .

Comment: `So every time you call this function you are resetting the value.` that is incorrect - any time the function is called it enters a new stack. There is an entirely new `exAS` defined - the old one is not touched. And since you get into a new stack, you eventually run against the maximum stack size, no more stacks can be created and the engine throws the `RangeError`.

Comment: I meant exAS value is being reset, in the sense of the loop. A new exAS is set in the memory you are correct.